# Set Report Viewer Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, report, reportviewer

I use reprot viewer in my project. (VS 2010 - asp.net project with c#)
the report viewer working and get the data from db, but I want to set the Title from the code,
so I had parameter to report ("title") and set TextBox to that,
and in the code wrote this:

```
ReportParameter p = new ReportParameter("title", "Title of Report");
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p });
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

and now the report freeze when it's Loading.
[image]

without the Parameter it's working fine..
Why?

Thank you!!!!

Comment: I solve it. the problem that I forget to place If(!IsPostBack) in the pageLoad

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the parameter definition has been added to the Report during the design.

To add a parameter to a report, from the menu choose Report > Report Parameters command. Press Add to add a parameter and add the title parameter.